# Генерация XML в C# (парсинг)

Tags: c#, парсер, xml

В данный момент занимаюсь парсингом *.L5K файла. В принципе из файла извлек все нужные данные через Split'ы. Застрял на моменте где нужно сгенерировать XML файл из извлеченных данных. Суть: имеются словари - DataTypes и Tags:

```
    public class DataType
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool _struct { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();

        public DataType(string DataTypeName, string DataTypeDescription)
        {
            name = DataTypeName;
            description = DataTypeDescription;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Tag
    {
        public string name = "";
        public string fullName = "";
        public string description = "";
        public bool isArray;
        public int lenght;
        public List<Tag> elements = new List<Tag>();
        public Tag(string TagName, string TagFullName)
        {
            name = TagName;
            fullName = TagFullName;
        }
    }
```

```
        Dictionary<string, Tag> Tags = new Dictionary<string, Tag>();
        Dictionary<string, DataType> DataTypes = new Dictionary<string, DataType>();
```

И таким образом пытаюсь сгенерировать XML файл используя элементы словарей DataTypes и Tags:

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("project");
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
            var dataTypeElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("appdata");
            rootNode.AppendChild(dataTypeElement);

            foreach (DataType dtype in DataTypes.Values)
            {
                var dataTypeName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("data");
                dataTypeElement.AppendChild(dataTypeName);  

                var dataTypeNameAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
                dataTypeNameAttr.Value = dtype.name;
                dataTypeName.Attributes.Append(dataTypeNameAttr);

                foreach (Tag tag_ in dtype.tags)
                {
                    var variableElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("variable");
                    dataTypeName.AppendChild(variableElement);

                    var nameAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
                    nameAttribute.Value = tag_.name;
                    variableElement.Attributes.Append(nameAttribute);
                }
            }
```

Вот маленькая часть что из этого у меня выходит:

```
     <project>
      <appdata>
       <data name="AIn">
        <variable name="Sts" />
        <variable name="Kod" />
        <variable name="I" />
        <variable name="S" />
        <variable name="V" />
        <variable name="AvgV" />
        <variable name="VP" />
        <variable name="k" />
        <variable name="p" />
        <variable name="pk" />
        <variable name="pp" />
        <variable name="cV" />
        <variable name="avgv_sum" />
        <variable name="avgv_count" />
        <variable name="s_pre" />
        <variable name="sf" />
        <variable name="SrvsBits" />
        <variable name="Ctrl" />
       </data>
      </appdata>
      <appdata>
       <data name="AInInt">
        <variable name="k" />
        <variable name="p" />
        <variable name="pk" />
        <variable name="pp" />
        <variable name="cV" />
        <variable name="avgv_sum" />
        <variable name="avgv_count" />
        <variable name="s_pre" />
        <variable name="sf" />
        <variable name="SrvsBits" />
        <variable name="Ctrl" />
       </data>
      </appdata>
     </project>
```

**А как на самом деле должен выглядеть XML файл:**

```
       <project>
        <appdata>
         <data name="AIn">
           <variable name="Sts" />
           <variable name="Kod" />
           <variable name="I" />
           <variable name="S" />
           <variable name="V" />
           <variable name="AvgV" />
           <variable name="VP" />
         </data>
        </appdata>
        <appdata>
         <data name="AInInt">
           <variable name="k" />
           <variable name="p" />
           <variable name="pk" />
           <variable name="pp" />
           <variable name="cV" />
           <variable name="avgv_sum" />
           <variable name="avgv_count" />
           <variable name="s_pre" />
           <variable name="sf" />
           <variable name="SrvsBits" />
         </data>
        </appdata>
       </project>
```

То есть как видно "variable names" начинается правильно с первого элемента а дальше выводится прям до конца что есть не хорошо, каждый элемент из DataTypes хранит в себе определенное количество "variable names". Нужно чтобы выводились лишь определенные "variable names" определенных DataTypes. Вот так.
Есть какие либо решения этой проблемы? Сталкивались ли вы чем то похожим? Поделитесь пожалуйста своими мыслями\решениями.
**Вот ссылка на полный [XML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BNmGpfRhX_8S3_6MZjqXNYTDRCvLH-Wo/view?usp=drivesdk) файл который у меня получается:**

Comment: У вас нигде нет никаких проверок, `Where`, etc. для фильтрации контента, который вы пишите в xml, чему же вы удивляетесь? :)

Comment: Вместо `XmlDocument` используйте более современный linq2xml, классы `XDocument`/`XElement`/`XAttribute` - код будет намного проще.

Answer (score 0):

1. У тебя в желаемом выходном файле закрывающего тега *data* нет - кривой xml-документ получается.
2. В желаемом выходном файле несколько блоков *appdata*, а в приведённом коде *appdata* создаётся только один, и он же везде используется. Видимо, нужен ещё один внешний цикл, где будут создаваться блоки *appdata*.

Comment: 1. Да, совсем забыл добавить ибо все от руки редачилось..

2. Блок appdata нормально создается для каждого DataTypes, хотя как видно создается только один. Если поместить внутри цикла то никаких изменений не наблюдается.